# Can't load animation using start frame and end frame [P5.Play]

Tags: p5.js

I'm trying to load an animation in preload using using the start frame and end frame, as the P5.Play reference specifies, and it only loads the first and last frame instead of prefilling all those between them. This wouldn't be an issue for animations with 15 or so frames but I have a few with 80+.

```
function preload() {
  chargeExplosion = loadAnimation('assets/chargeExplosion/frame0000.png', 'assets/chargeExplosion/frame0081.png');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500)
}

function draw() {
  explosion1 = createSprite(width / 2, height / 2, 40, 40);
  explosion1.addAnimation('boom', chargeExplosion);
}
```

This code is oversimplified as I have over few hundred lines of code but I have made sure that absolutely nothing is interfering. The animation worked fine when I preloaded every single frame individually, I just really don't want to have to do that for the rest of them.

Answer (score 1):

1. Sprites in p5.play are persistent. You want to create them during setup (or possibly in response to some event).
2. In order to display the sprites you have created you need to call `drawSprites()`

```js
let chargeExplosion;
let explosion1;

function preload() {
  chargeExplosion = loadAnimation('https://www.paulwheeler.us/files/AnimFrame00.png', 'https://www.paulwheeler.us/files/AnimFrame02.png');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  explosion1 = createSprite(width / 2, height / 2, 40, 40);
  chargeExplosion.frameDelay = 30;
  explosion1.addAnimation('boom', chargeExplosion);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  drawSprites();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.paulwheeler.us/files/p5.play.js?r=0"></script>
```